# Difficulties Using FFmpeg to Take Lossless Excerpt from .mpg to .mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, lossless

I want output.mp4 to contain a lossless copy of video starting at 00:00:39 and ending at 00:01:29 in input.mpg. I tried this (using Windows 10):

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:39 -i input.mpg -to 00:01:29 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

This produced errors:

```
track 1: codec frame size is not set
Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0
pts has no value
```

Also, the output did not consist of a 50-second excerpt (i.e., 0:39 to 1:29). Instead, it was ~1:29 in duration, as if I had used -t instead of -to.

I found that I could mitigate the error messages by first remuxing input.mpg to input.mp4 using this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg input.mp4
```

But I was not certain that this command was producing lossless output. It was relatively slow, and it produced a file less than half the size of the original. On the other hand, toward the end of its many progress reports, it did refer to "muxing overhead," suggesting that it was remuxing rather than re-encoding.

After that remuxing effort, I re-ran the first command shown above, revising it to refer to input.mp4 instead of input.mpg. This produced no error messages, and the excerpt did begin at the right place. Unfortunately, output.mp4 was still too long: 1:32, not 1:29 nor 0:50.

I plan to edit output.mp4, with other video clips, in Adobe Premiere Elements 2020, which I have found to be finicky in terms of what it will accept, and unstable in the sense of crashing whenever it feels things are not perfect.

My question is: how can I revise the first command shown above to produce the desired lossless 50-second excerpt from input.mpg?

Here, the complete log from the first command:

```
D:\>ffmpeg -ss 00:00:39 -i input.mpg -to 00:01:29 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4

ffmpeg version git-2020-06-12-38737b3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf

  libavutil      56. 54.100 / 56. 54.100

  libavcodec     58. 92.100 / 58. 92.100

  libavformat    58. 46.101 / 58. 46.101

  libavdevice    58. 11.100 / 58. 11.100

  libavfilter     7. 86.100 /  7. 86.100

  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100

  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100

  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100

Input #0, mpeg, from 'input.mpg':

  Duration: 00:07:53.38, start: 0.213367, bitrate: 6313 kb/s

    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet

    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc

    Side data:

      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 8000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A

    Stream #0:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s

[mp4 @ 0000029a2189fc00] track 1: codec frame size is not set

Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':

  Metadata:

    encoder         : Lavf58.46.101

    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc

    Side data:

      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 8000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A

    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)

  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

[mp4 @ 0000029a2189fc00] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly

[mp4 @ 0000029a2189fc00] pts has no value

    Last message repeated 371 times

frame= 1397 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   35072kB time=00:00:46.15 bitrate=6225.3kbits/s spe[mp4 @ 0000029a2189fc00] pts has no value

    Last message repeated 344 times

frame= 2681 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   67808kB time=00:01:28.99 bitrate=6241.7kbits/s speed=94.2x

video:65658kB audio:2100kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.073772%
```

Comment: This is going to become my 'sw rec' of the year… I often wonder why people struggle with command-line video solutions when one of the world's finest video editing suites is available ***free*** for personal use. [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/) - Mac, Win & Nix.

Comment: I don't use it much tbh, I'm a stills photographer mainly & for video I used to use FCP predominantly. However,  the last project I did was a showreel made up out of "whatever I could grab". The source material was a mixture of .mov, .mp4 & .m4v - zero issues at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DaVinci Resolve. My questions: (1) Does it produce lossless output without enormous file inflation? (2) Can I set it up to produce automated output from 100 different clips? Because once I get the syntax down, I plan to use Excel to generate commands for similar excerpts from a large number of input files.

Comment: my best guess is 'probably not'. It's a video editing suite, not an automation routine.

Comment: Show the complete log from command #1.

Comment: @llogan Posted as requested.

Comment: I saw but too lazy to parse messy formatting.

Comment: Messy ... how so? It came out of the CMD window all run together, with no line breaks. This was the best I could make of it.